# How to build a project from GitHub?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm new to using GitHub and I need to build  the latest project from https://github.com/TantalumMobile/Tantalum but I don't know what to do with the zip I downloaded from the site.

What I got after extracting from this zip was a Tantalum-Master folder and inside the same layout as the project in GitHub but if I try to import this folder into Eclipse then I get the example projects imported and not the project with the classes I'm interested.

Do I have to reference somehow project like in Visual Studio? How do I build the jar? Do I have to paste the source folder into my project? Does Eclipse needs a plugin to use this kind of projects? Do I need a specific IDE to build this kind of project?

Comment: Git or Github has nothing to do with it; building is project-specific. Github just stores the files.

Comment: then how do I build this kind of project? The only instructions I found in it was to create my own project and that's about it. I'm not familiar at all with how to work with these kind of projects.

Comment: @UrielArvizu, you may want to start with [Gradle's documentation](http://www.gradle.org/learn).

Comment: The project uses gradle, but unfortunately, doesn't use the gradle wrapper. You should be able to build the project by downloading gradle (google it), and then run, from the root of the project, `gradle build`. If that doesn't work, the submit an issue to the github project asking for clarifications on how to build the project. The developers of this project seem to use IntelliJ IDEA and not Eclipse. With IntelliJ, launching `gradle idea`should create a IDEA project.

Comment: that sounds like the way to go, post it as an answer so I can mark it

Comment: Github page also has recommendations on how to get started and links to example projects.